# PL/SQL: Decrypt a file encrypted with PGP (Have private key, key passphrase, and encrypted file)

Tags: encryption, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, pgp, oracle19c

Currently we have a manual process in place that I think could be automated. There is an automated process to pull a file from "somewhere" and put it in a folder we access. Then there is a manual process in which someone logs in, runs gnu key manager and decrypts the file with a PGP Private Key (Version: GnuPG v2) and Key Passphrase. Then, a PL/SQL program runs and processes that (decrypted) file.
I wanted to see if there is a method to decrypt it within the PL/SQL program that is processing the file. I did find a commercial library called ORA_PGP but we don't have the ability to purchase/implement libraries like that. I'm not sure if we already have it installed/purchased but I tried running it just like an example was given, and it did not work.

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
27/11     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
27/22     PLS-00201: identifier 'ORA_PGP.DECRYPT' must be declared
Errors: check compiler log
```

Here is the code I ran to do that:

```
create or replace procedure P_DECRYPT_FILE (
P_IN_DIR in varchar2, P_IN_FILE in varchar2, P_IN_KEY in varchar2, P_OUT_DIR in varchar2, P_OUT_FILE in varchar2, P_IN_KEY_PASSWORD in varchar2) as
 
  IN_FILE UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  IN_REC               varchar2 (1024);
  IN_EOF               boolean;
  OUT_FILE UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  OUT_REC              varchar2 (1024);
  PRIVATE_KEY UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  V_COUNT              number (8) := 0;
  V_PROGRAM_SECTION    varchar2 (100);

begin
   V_PROGRAM_SECTION := 'open IN_FILE';
   IN_FILE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(P_IN_DIR,P_IN_FILE,'R');
   V_PROGRAM_SECTION := 'open IN_KEY';
   PRIVATE_KEY := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(P_IN_DIR,P_IN_KEY,'R');
   V_PROGRAM_SECTION := 'open OUT_FILE';
   OUT_FILE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(P_OUT_DIR,P_OUT_FILE,'W');
  
   loop
       V_PROGRAM_SECTION := 'read IN_FILE';
       X.P_GET_NEXTLINE(IN_FILE,IN_REC,IN_EOF);
       exit when IN_EOF; 
       V_COUNT := V_COUNT + 1;
       V_PROGRAM_SECTION := 'decrypt operation';
          OUT_REC := ORA_PGP.DECRYPT(
           MESSAGE => IN_REC,
           PRIVATE_KEY => PRIVATE_KEY,
           KEY_PASSWORD => P_IN_KEY_PASSWORD
           );
       -- write out file
       V_PROGRAM_SECTION := 'write OUT_FILE';
       UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(OUT_FILE, OUT_REC);
   end LOOP; 

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('RECS COUNTED: ' || V_COUNT);
   V_PROGRAM_SECTION := 'close files';
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (IN_FILE);
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (OUT_FILE);

exception
  when others then 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('ERR- ' || SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1,100) || ' -- ' || V_PROGRAM_SECTION || ' -- ' || out_rec); 
     /* Close all opened files. */
     UTL_FILE.FCLOSE_ALL;
end P_DECRYPT_FILE;
```

I've been researching in DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT but I'm not quite certain what syntax to use/where to put my key and key passphrase. I've also tried researching DBMS_CRYPTO but I'm having the same confusion there too. Can anyone assist a bit?

Comment: If you can't afford to license a library, I certainly wouldn't try to do this in PL/SQL.  If you are using an external table to process the file, you could add a preprocessor directive that called out to the operating system to run whatever commands you'd run manually to decrypt the file.  But it sounds more like you want a shell script/ batch file that runs the OS commands to decrypt the file and then invokes the PL/SQL code to process the file.

Comment: Also, DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT was deprecated and replaced by DBMS_CRYPTO. In general, encryption algorithms aren't very interchangeable: if it was encrypted with PGP you're going to have to decrypt it with PGP; there's nothing in DBMS_CRYPTO that would directly apply that I'm aware of.

Comment: @JustinCave It's less about 'can't afford' and more about 'don't have the authority'. We have someone else who is supposed to set up an automated process on the OS to decrypt the file but he's a busy person and never has time. I was hoping to find a solution in PL/SQL so we could move forward with the task without waiting for the other group.